# ngx-translate with JSONfile stored in server

Tags: angular, angular-translate, ngx-translate

I am trying to feed the translation key-value pair in my system through a JSON file stored in a server. The server has a file named "en.json". What I have currently done:

`App Module Imports`:

```js
     TranslateModule.forRoot({
          loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useClass: CustomLoader, // USE THIS FOR API
            deps: [HttpClient]
          }
        })

    export class CustomLoader implements TranslateLoader {
        
          constructor() { }
        
          public getTranslation(lang: String): Observable<any> {
              let data;
              fetch('https://xxxx.xxx.xxxx.windows.net/lang/en.json')
              .then(response => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                  throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
                }
                return response.json();
              })
              .then(json => {
                 data = json;
                console.log('result', data); 
    // contains the JSON data eg {"key.name": "name", "key.address": "address"}
              })
              .catch(function () {
                this.dataError = true;
              })
            return of(data);
          }
        
        }
```

I could find different ways to load the translation data through an API call that returns the JSON data or read a JSON file from the local directory but was unable to find anything related to it.

Comment: Didn’t this work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52165296/angular6-load-translations-using-api-call-to-backend-using-ngx-translate?

Comment: @Vikas I tried that as well, it works when the API being used returns JSON data, not a JSON file.

Comment: Ohh I see, I did work with fetching json file with ngx-translate, but in my case we were using static server side rendering , Have a look at this https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/754 , something might help you out

Answer (score 2):

Try below customloader

```
export class CustomLoader implements TranslateLoader  {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}
  getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any> {
    const header = new HttpHeaders({
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    });
    const apiAddress = 'https://xxxx.xxx.xxxx.windows.net/lang/en.json';
    return this.httpClient.get(apiAddress, { headers: header});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any way to achieve the required result so we end up reading the JSON file itself in the backend and returning the JSON as an API response.