# Angular - Download json translation file from server and use it in browser

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I have a json file that I download from the server, this file is managed from the server and contains translations that I use for server error messages. Is it possible to use this file and overwrite an empty json file that I have in my frontend app? Or is it reccomended to store this json inside localstorage? What's the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

I'll do this on server site. So I transmit (on login as example) my current language and the server gives the response in the current language to the client.

Is this no option for you look to `ngx-translate`. It's a library that uses `Pipes` to make a multi lang app (and so much more!). [Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngx-translate/core) is the NPM link.

With this you can use a **custom loader** which load your `JSON` which includes the translated texts from a given `URL`. Normally this url is your assets folder. But you can do it with external link like this ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68469749/4472932) is the answer an Stackoverflow):

```
export class CustomLoader implements TranslateLoader  {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}
  getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any> {
    const header = new HttpHeaders({
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    });
    const apiAddress = 'https://xxxx.xxx.xxxx.windows.net/lang/en.json';
    return this.httpClient.get(apiAddress, { headers: header});
  }
}
```

But the new syntax you need looks a bit different. Here, in the `App Module` you need to use `ngx-translate`s `HttpBackend` instead of Angulars `HttpClient` But you can read more in the official documentation of `ngx-translate`.

```
imports: [
...
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpBackend],
      },
    }),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}

function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpBackend) {
  return new MultiTranslateHttpLoader(http, [
    { prefix: './assets/i18n/', suffix: '.json' },
  ]);
}
```

[Here](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-add-internationalization-translations-in-angular-backend-integration-and-lazy-loaded-bd394262727) is another good link, too.

> Then we need to create our own loader to load the translations from an external API server. The custom loader needs to implement the TranslateLoader interface which has a required method getTranslation() that returns an Observable. We will put the custom loader class in a new file translate-loader.ts:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

export class CustomTranslateLoader implements TranslateLoader {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${environment.apiHost}/translations/${lang}`);
  }
}
```