# Is there any platform where I can update my translations files for instance en.json with ngx translate?

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I am looking for a plaftorm where I can update my translations file and it can be retrieve as a json file to place it on my angular app using ngx translate. Any recommendations. ?
Something like BabelEdit ?

Comment: I reckon you're looking for something like this, ie use HTTP calls to load translations from backend - [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52165296/angular6-load-translations-using-api-call-to-backend-using-ngx-translate)

Comment: Actually it is for a translator, it needs a UI implemented where a translator gets the Job done on it

Comment: I have found one,  https://lokalise.com/  is this a good one ?

Comment: Please note that tool/product/service recommendation questions are off-topic here. Please don't post links to offsite tools.

Answer (score 0):

1. u can try to make some hash for all translation for compare current translations with some placed on server side
2. put this hash into some config.json file placed on server
3. u must write logic worked by some condition (for example only for production mode) where u set interval and check your current translationsHash with loaded from server and if them different - call to reload translations file

u need gulp/webpack/babel for making hash file